# 422Unprocessable Entity with custom decorator FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have created a custom decorator which acts as a logger, however when I attach it to the router or endpoint of fast API to log the details, I get this error :

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Also, I get a response, which  kinda means that there's a field missing :

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "query",
                "self"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my decorator class :

```
class LogEndpointAction(DatabaseClass):

    def __init__(self, entity_name: str, action: str):
        self.entity_name = entity_name
        self.action = action

    def __call__(self, func: Callable):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            request: Request = kwargs.get('request')
            print(' args ', args)
            print(' req ', request)
            current_user = await self._authenticate_user(request)
            response = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            body = await request.json() if request.method in ["POST", "PUT", "PATCH"] else {}

            log_data = {
                'tenant_id': '',
                'user_id': '',
                'full_name': '',
                'roles': [],
                'email': '',
                'entity_name': self.entity_name,
                'data': json.dumps(body),
                'i18n_key': self.action
            }

            await self.db.execute(query=INSERT_LOG_QUERY, values=log_data)
            return response


        return wrapper
```

Then I call it to an endpoint :

```
@LogEndpointAction(entity_name='Sales', action='Get all')
@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Comment: Hi @Chris, I think it doesn't matter, because even If I remove the class extended the same error arises

Comment: When I just remove all the logic and the DatabaseClass, and just add a decorator, still the error happens, what I was thinking is maybe we have to somehow restrict overriding the FastAPI objects